# How do I create dot functions with parameters?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function equivalent to

```
{}.setAttribute(..., ...);
```

but with parameters, e.g:

```
var selector = {};
function selector.newAttrib(a, x){
  selector.setAttribute(a, x);
};
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you put `var` keywords inside function parameters?

Comment: Highly suggest getting familiar with javascript's syntax to save yourself some headaches

Comment: @Barmar thanks, removed the `var´ keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to assign it to `selector`.

```
var selector = {};
selector.newAttrib = function(a, x){
  this.setAttribute(a, x);
};
```

or make it a part of the object from the get go.

```
var selector = {
   newAttrib: function(a, x){
     this.setAttribute(a, x);
   }
};
```

Comment: Don't think `function(var a, var x)` is valid syntax. You can't use `var` in function header

Answer (score 0):

You can set it just like any other object property, like so:

`selector.myfunction = function (param1, param2) { ... }`